# Window.Show Closing the application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application where at one point I am closing all windows and I want to relaunch one of the closed windows. But the problem is when I say `Window.Show();` the breakpoint shows the Actual Height and Actual Width to be 0 and after the line is executed, the entire app shuts down. Why, is it being garbage collected?

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (jsonAssayViewModel.IsLiveProgress)
    {
        var res = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.MessageBox.Show(
                   Application.Current.TryFindResource("CloseRun").ToString(),
                   "Confirm dialog",
                   MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                   MessageBoxImage.Question
               );
        if (res == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            jsonAssayViewModel.PreventClosingWindow = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    //Raise the close event....
    if (CloseCurrentProgressWindow != null)
    {
        CloseCurrentProgressWindow();
    }
    var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    if (window != null && window.Tag.ToString() == "Success")
    {
        if ((sender as Button).Content.ToString() == Application.Current.TryFindResource("Done").ToString())
        {
            var AllWindows = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
                                               .Where(win => win.IsLoaded);
            if (AllWindows.Count() > 2)
            {
                jsonAssayViewModel.SelectedAssay = null;
                jsonAssayViewModel.SelectedVolume = string.Empty;
                foreach (Window win in App.Current.Windows)
                {
                    win.Close();
                }
                NextGenDGRunSetupWindow wn = new NextGenDGRunSetupWindow();
                wn.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the NextGenDGRunSetupWindow I have the following

```
public NextGenDGRunSetupWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //idleTimeDetector = new IdleDetector(this); //1 minute
    readJsonViewModel = ReadJsonAssayViewModel.ReadJsonAssayViewModelInstance;
    //idleTimeDetector.IsIdle += IdleTime_IsIdle;
    readJsonViewModel.LaunchErrorWindowFromAnywhere += ReadJsonViewModel_LaunchErrorWindowFromAnywhere;
}
```

Comment: You do `foreach (Window win in App.Current.Windows) {win.Close();}`. This will also close your main program window -- which is akin to saying goodbye to your program, unless you change the [ShutdownMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode#System_Windows_Application_ShutdownMode) of your application.

Comment: Even if i move the NextGenDGRunSetupWindow wn = new NextGenDGRunSetupWindow(); wn.Show() logic before the foreach loop thats exiting the application as well. Ok I will try setting the ShutDownMode

Comment: Since i assume you are a beginner, i advise against changing ShutdownMode, as you would either need to kind of manually wire the shutdown logic or pay very close attention which windows you have to close when to shutdown your application. I guess it is a much easier approach to simply avoid closing the main window...

Comment: Thanks exactly what I am looking for, ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown" works fine

Comment: You could however switch your main window to another window (that window then becoming the main window), by simply setting the [Application.MainWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.mainwindow#System_Windows_Application_MainWindow) property to the new main window. (This approach should then also take care of taskbar preview thumbnail, i hope...)

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind but I only want 1 of the windows to be my main window.

Comment: Okay, never mind. If you got OnExplicitShutdown working already, i retract my assumption about you being a beginner :)

Comment: Its ok sometimes I do miss the basics :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing every Window that's loaded in your application. Since `Show()` does not block, the moment the method finishes executing the startup Window closes and your application exits.  You have a couple of options here:

1. Use `wn.ShowDialog();` - this blocks the current method until the window is closed; or
2. Don't close the main window, whichever it is, in your `foreach`.
3. Change [`Application.ShutDownMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to either `ShutDownMode.OnExplicitShutdown` or `ShutDownMode.OnLastWindowClose`

Comment: Thanks but setting the ShutDownMode in App.xaml worked fine. I guess thats an option too.

Comment: @NikhilANS I added that option as well